# Control of the Hessian of the distance function at infinity

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, riemannian-geometry, differential-equations

Let $(M,g)$ be a complete noncompact manifold and $r$ is the distance function to a fixed point. We assume that the sectional curvature $|Rm|(x) \le K(r(x))$ where $K(r)=\frac{1}{1+r^k}$ for some $k>2$.

If we denote the Hessian of $r$ by the matrix $U$, then from the Riccati equation, we know that
$$
U'+U^2=-R
$$
where R is some sectional curvature term.

My question is, can we have some good control of $U$ when $r$ is large? More precisely, for all large $r$, can we show
$$
|U-\frac{1}{r}g_r|\le \frac{C}{r^{m}}
$$
for some positve $m=m(k)$, where $g_r$ is the metric restricted on the level set?